# How can I fix this transparency issue?

Tags: transparency

I'm pretty new to Blender and I'm having some trouble with transparency. I tried searching up for the solution, but I can't seem to understand any of them.

The objects I'm having trouble with are the car, the grates at the back and the face. It appears that they are somewhat transparent.

[image]

I can also provide the .blend file.

Comment: Hello, it's hard to understand your picture and your problem, maybe tell a bit more about what are your objects and what's happening?

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying this earlier, but the objects I'm having trouble with are the car, the grates at the back and the face. It appears that some parts of these models are transparent.

Comment: It is very hard to guess what you did or didn't do from just image. Please edit your post and add more information.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on them and reset everything. It works in both render engines.

[image: hope it's help]